# How to check whether a string starts with a substring

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a very simple script which copies a file to a path provided by the user as a parameter and I would like to make sure the path starts with */var/log/messages*.

So I've written this:

```
if [[ $2 -ne /var/log/messages/* ]]
then
  echo "Incorrect path, must be under /var/log/messages/"
  exit
fi
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can do `[[ $2 != /var/log/messages/* ]]` (incorrect path)

Comment: `-ne` is for arithmetic comparisons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
if [[ "$2" != "/var/log/messages/"* ]]
then
  echo "Incorrect path, must be under /var/log/messages/"
  exit
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [regular expressions as well](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression#regular_expression_matching) (starting from Bash version 3). Just remember this:

> Every quoted part of the regular expression is taken literally, even if it contains regular expression special characters.

In this case, you could do something like this:

```
if [[ ! "$2" =~ ^"/var/log/messages/" ]]
then
   echo "Incorrect path, must be under /var/log/messages/"
   exit
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You should in general provide a minimal non-working example. However, I suspect you want:

```
if [[ $2 != /var/log/messages/* ]]
then
  echo "Incorrect path, must be under /var/log/messages/"
  exit
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dirname`:

```
if [[ `dirname $2` != "/var/log/messages" ]]
then
  echo "Incorrect path, must be under /var/log/messages/"
  exit
fi
```

Comment: This doesn't account for subdirectories.

Comment: This is true, I thought he wanted to make sure that $2 was in /var/log/messages **only**

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED:

```
...
case $2 in
/var/log/messages/*) ;;
    # do whatever...
*)
    echo "incorrect ..."
    break
    ;;
esac
...
```